# setRequestedOrientation changes the global system orientation preference

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, orientation

good evening people.

Simple question

why

```
mActivity.setRequestedOrientation(force ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

turns 'auto rotate' from device's quick settings icon ON ?
seems like setRequestedOrientation() globally changes system preference regardless activity which called setRequestedOrientation is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

I bet its some additional "feature" or behavior of your Android version modified by manufacturer. check on some other device from different manufacturer or at least different Android version. you can also try to use emulator

I have some old tablet with clean Android version, which have broken gyro/accelerometer, works only for few hours after device reset. so I've disabled auto-rotate and set fixed horizontal orientation on it. still when I run my app with similar code to yours forcing portrait mode then it will show in portrait mode as intended, but when I exit my app then whole interface/previous app runs in horizontal - still no auto-rotate option enabled